# Manipulating stringification of booleans

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to manipulate the way booleans are stringified?

Changing `Boolean.prototype.toString` doesn't seem to help.

Here my tests within mozrepl and FF3.

```
repl> Boolean.prototype.toString=function (){return this==true ? "1" : ""}
function() {…}
repl> a.toString()
""
repl> a=true
true
repl> a.toString()
"1"
repl> a+""
"true"
repl> a=false
false
repl> a+""
"false"
```

My understanding of the ECMA specification is that `+` should call `toString()`.

---

UPDATE:

OK I found the answer!

When ECMA speaks about [`ToString()`](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-9.8) it doesn't mean the JS method `toString()`.

> These operators are not a part of the language; they are defined here to aid the 
>   specification of the semantics of the language.

see http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-9

Thanks for the help so far.

Doesn't seem to be possible... :(

Comment: Huh - this works with `Array`, though: http://jsfiddle.net/nrabinowitz/ySEx6/1/

Comment: Even if `a + ""` delegated to `Boolean.prototype` for consistency with `new Boolean(a) + ""`, it would result in a call to `Boolean.prototype.valueOf`, not `Boolean.prototype.toString`.

Comment: @nrabinowitz, `Array`s are objects, not primitives so there is no way that a primitive array can behave differently from a wrapper object.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why would you ever want to do that?

Comment: @minitech: I'm investigating the possibility of a direct Perl to JS translator and this is one of the incompatible edge cases.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose `.toString()` is called on the `Boolean` version of the native boolean type (Boolean is an Object but the native type isn't, same with Numbers) and `+` is overloaded by the browser to convert a boolean to a string natively.

This question *has* been asked before (and I'm fairly sure what I said was the answer) but I can't seem to find it.

Comment: Even if you do `a = new Boolean(true);` to make a non-primitive boolean and then do `alert(a+"");` you still get `"true"`, this is a little weird.

Comment: Primitives and instances of the wrapper object are never treated differently. Thats the basic idea of the wrapper objects.

Comment: @noboby, That's because `a+""` causes `a.valueOf` to be called, not `a.toString`.

Comment: @Mike Samuel: when objects are evaluated for a binary operation  .valueOf() will of course be called. The point is (was) which method will be called to do the  `+` with one of the operands being a string. ECMA is specific about the `ToString()` "operand", it's hardcoded and I confused it with `.toString()`

Comment: @LanX, I was addressing "`alert(new Boolean(true)+"")` you still get true, this is a little weird."

Comment: @LanX "Primitives and instances of the wrapper object are never treated differently." that is not entirely true, `var a = new Boolean(false); var b = false; if(a) alert("a"); if(b) alert("b");` alerts a but not b.

Comment: @nonbody: your right, objects (except `null`) are always true. What I meant to say was that always the same methods are called. But unfortunately `.valueOf()` isn't called in a boolean context. :-(

Comment: @Mike Samuel: What happens for an object a is equivalent to `ToString(a.valueOf())+""` so `.valueOf()` isn't a replacement for `.toString()`! But I think we mean the same and it's just a problem of wording.  :-)

Comment: @LanX, `valueOf` gets called, so when the two aren't equivalent, the result is `valueOf`.  `Boolean.prototype.valueOf = function () { return "V" };  Boolean.prototype.toString = function () { return "S" }; alert(new Boolean + " ; " + String(new Boolean))` -> 
`V ; S`

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you found the answer, but for reference:

Section [11.6.1](http://es5.github.com/#x11.6.1) explains what happens when `+` is invoked on a string and another value.

> If Type(lprim) is String or Type(rprim) is String, then
>   Return the String that is the result of concatenating ToString(lprim) followed by ToString(rprim)

and as you noted, *ToString* is not just a call to `toString`.

Section [9.8](http://es5.github.com/#x9.8) explains what *ToString* does.

> The abstract operation ToString converts its argument to a value of type String according to Table 13:
>
> Boolean
>   If the argument is true, then the result is "true".
>   If the argument is false, then the result is "false".

Note that for objects, `valueOf` is invoked, not `toString` because *ToString* delegates to *ToPrimitive* which for native objects ends up in [*DefaultValue*](http://es5.github.com/#x8.12.8) with type hint undefined

> Let valueOf be the result of calling the [[Get]] internal method of object O with argument "valueOf".
>
> If IsCallable(valueOf) is true then,
>
> Let val be the result of calling the [[Call]] internal method of valueOf, with O as the this value and an empty argument list.
>
> If val is a primitive value, return val.

If you want `"" + new Boolean(a)` to delegate to `Boolean.prototype.toString` you would first have to override `Boolean.prototype.valueOf` to return a non-primitive value which is bad manners.